# How to set text centerHorizontal in popup menu

Tags: android

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_question_popup, popup.getMenu());
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(onMenuItemClickListener);

            popup.show();
```

I implemented PopupMenu on a Button. 
When I click the button, the menu appears. 
But the texts are always on the left side.

What I want to do is... 
When the popup menu is shown, I want each of the text to align center.

Answer (score 1):

YOu can use SpannableString:

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings);
        SpannableString s = new SpannableString("Setting");

        s.setSpan(new AlignmentSpan.Standard(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER), 0, s.length(), 0);

        item.setTitle(s);
```

Result:

[image]